# ERStudio macro String Split

Tags: macros

I'm developing a macro for ER Studio 9.1.1 When I use Split function it's highlighted as it's a part of language. Macros are written in SAX Basic (v6), according to SAX Basic manual Split should be supported, but this code gives me error:

```
Dim strArray As String
Dim data As String
data = "one, two, three"
strArray = Split(data, ", ")
```

The error is "Expecting an existing scalar var".

So my question is, is the Split supported and what is the scalar var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out, ER Studio macros doesn't support Split function.
If you need Split functionality you have to write custom code.

Answer (score 0):

a possibility:

You have a function or sub already called split. To test this, see if `VBA.Split(` works. if it does, then you need to rename your own function, or always use vba.split

There is another fault:
As you have strArray defined as a string, it will fail on the split, as it can't put the array into a single variable. either remove the definition, so all you have is `Dim strArray`, or define it as an array with `Dim strArray() As String`

Comment: Your suggested solution does not solve the problem. As I stated in my question, I'm not using VBA. Also I don't have other function subroutine called split. You are right about the variable definition, though.

ER Studio simply doesn't support split function.